# How does AngularJS traverse the Angular template (HTML + AngularJS Directives) asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asynchronous

I was reading the AngularJS book by Brad Green and Shyama Sheshadari and came across the following text:

> The basic startup flow looks like this:
>   1. A user requests the first page of your application.
>   2. The user’s browser makes an HTTP connection to your server and loads the in
>   dex.html page containing your template.
>   3. Angular loads into the page, waits for the page to be fully loaded, and then looks
>   for ng-app to define its template boundaries.
>   4. Angular traverses the template and looks for directives and bindings. This results
>   in registration of listeners and DOM manipulation, as well as fetching initial data
>   from the server. The end result of this work is that the app is bootstrapped and the
>   template is converted into view as a DOM.
>   5. You connect to your server to load additional data you need to show the user as
>   needed.
>
> Steps 1 through 3 are standard for every Angular app. It’s in steps 4
>   and 5 that you have choices. These steps can happen synchronously or
>   asynchronously. For performance, the data your app needs to display to
>   the user on the first view can come down with the HTML template to
>   avoid multiple requests.

How can step 4 happen asynchronously? Also, what does the author mean when he says that for the first iteration the data can be sent along with the HTML? The HTML will always have the data come from Angular directives, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML contains a directive then that directive might load a template asynchronously e.g.

And as for embedding data:
Imagine your application needs a user object. Now a controller might load that data from the server so that it can be used by the application. But this would take another request.

Instead you could embed that user object directly into the page like this, e.g.:

```
<script ...>
var user = {
            name: 'Me',
            ...
           };
```

The application can immediately use the data without making an additional request.

Comment: Step 4 says that Angular traverses the template and converts it to final DOM. Is it possible to have this process run asynchronously? I didn't understand what the authors meant here.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by embedding data?
If I have an angular app and I write something like this:
<p>{{greeting}}</p>
then this will always come from angular. There's no way to load it first time and then subsequently load it using angular.

Comment: Can you explain a couple more things?
How does a directive load template async? Any example or link?

As far as user object is concerned first the data will come from user object and later this same object will be updated via service. Is that correct?